# Removing a cell from a UICollectionView has a weird animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview

I have a weird animation/behaviour when removing an item from a collection view. It happens only when I have two items and that I remove the second item first. Here are two gif.

The first gif is the expected animation, it happens when I delete the first item.
[image]

The second gif is the wrong behaviour, it looks like the entire collection view is being reloaded:
[image]

Here is the method called to remove the item when clicking on the button:

```swift
@objc func removeCell(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: itemIndex, section: 0)
        let indexPaths = [indexPath]
        viewModels.remove(at: itemIndex)
        collectionView.deleteItems(at: indexPaths)
        pageControl.numberOfPages = min(10, viewModels.count)
        tableViewDelegate?.performTableViewBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the expected behavior you showed is first selecting the next/previous cell and after that updating the datasource.

Comment: Hmmm, the number of time I go back and forth on both cells actually doesn't change the behaviour of the dismissal. And I'm no clicking on any cell, I just tap on the button to dismiss it.

Comment: I mean, in order to achieve the expected behavior I think you should programmatically select the next/previous cell, and when the selection animation is done, you should remove the item from the datasource. But again, I'm not sure.

Comment: you dont/ need this line:         tableViewDelegate?.performTableViewBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
assuming the collectionview is nested inside the UITableViewCell. you're not updating the tableview you're updating the collection view, remove that line, see what happens